# EXTJS 4.2 best practices about paging toolbar binded to a local store

Tags: javascript, extjs4.2, sencha-architect

I have an AJAX store that fetches all the records from the server.

I want to bind the paging toolbar with the store for use with Grids and Combo boxes.

By using the store, I am looking to avoid making further AJAX calls to the server.

Sencha docs point to using Ext.ux.data.PagingStore for this task, but the link related to local paging on the sencha docs site points to a forum which strikes me as a bit odd.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?71532-Ext.ux.data.PagingStore-v0.5

I found a great example from 2011 here

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/12/extjs-pagingmemoryproxy-ajax-json-data.html

But it’s now 2014, using EXTJS4.2 thus the framework has evolved.

My question is as follows, is Ext.ux.data.PagingStore still the best/preferred way from Sencha to go about doing this? , am I overburdening the client by using this method?

Thanks

Comment: Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy still can be used in ExtJS 4.2.1, it works well

Comment: Thanks Dart, works well, just like you said,  also, I was able to enable remoteFilter in order to search the entire store.